# In detail explanation on how to use DeepSort

Tags: python, object-tracking

[Deep SORT](https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort) Github does not give much information on how to use it e.g.

- what inputs it expects in what format
- which function in which code file handles the input
- What are the outputs

The github lists the code files.

> In package deep_sort is the main tracking code:
>
> - detection.py: Detection base class.
> - kalman_filter.py: A Kalman filter implementation and concrete parametrization for image space filtering.
> - linear_assignment.py: This module contains code for min cost matching and the matching cascade.
> - iou_matching.py: This module contains the IOU matching metric.
> - nn_matching.py: A module for a nearest neighbor matching metric.
> - track.py: The track class contains single-target track data such as Kalman state, number of hits, misses, hit streak, associated feature vectors, etc.
> - tracker.py: This is the multi-target tracker class.
>   The deep_sort_app.py expects detections in a custom format, stored in .npy files. These can be computed from MOTChallenge detections using generate_detections.py. We also provide pre-generated detections.

By looking at `tracker.py`, I guess `update` method seems like the interface to feed the data about the detected objects. But what to do after?

```
    def update(self, detections):
        """Perform measurement update and track management.
        Parameters
        ----------
        detections : List[deep_sort.detection.Detection]
            A list of detections at the current time step.
        """
```

The detected object seems to be provided as the instance of Detection class in `detection.py`. But not sure exactly what data to use.

```
class Detection(object):
    """
    This class represents a bounding box detection in a single image.
    Parameters
    ----------
    tlwh : array_like
        Bounding box in format `(x, y, w, h)`.
    confidence : float
        Detector confidence score.
    feature : array_like
        A feature vector that describes the object contained in this image.
    Attributes
    ----------
    tlwh : ndarray
        Bounding box in format `(top left x, top left y, width, height)`.
    confidence : ndarray
        Detector confidence score.
    feature : ndarray | NoneType
        A feature vector that describes the object contained in this image.
    """

    def __init__(self, tlwh, confidence, feature):
        self.tlwh = np.asarray(tlwh, dtype=np.float)
        self.confidence = float(confidence)
        self.feature = np.asarray(feature, dtype=np.float32)
```

## Question

Instead of reverse engineering the sample application, are there resources that explain the input, output, formats to use?

## Research

There are multiple articles and githubs implementing object tracking with Yolo and DeepSort but it does not explain it either.

- [Object Tracking using DeepSORT in TensorFlow 2](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/object-tracking-using-deepsort-in-tensorflow-2-ec013a2eeb4f)
- [ObjectTracking-DeepSORT-YOLOv3-TF2](https://github.com/anushkadhiman/ObjectTracking-DeepSORT-YOLOv3-TF2/blob/master/object_tracker.py)

Answer (score 1):

There are no good sources what I know. But understanding how the data flows in DeepSORT will get you a long way. This is the data flow for [BoTSORT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.14651.pdf), which builds on top of DeepSORT. The data flow is anyways very similar for both tracking algorithms as the differences are minimal: [image] Understading this flowchart may help you understand how to use the building blocks in DeepSORT. The rest will be reading docstrings to get the right in out/data format for the specific methods in the repo you chose.